# $scope.variable in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't understand a behaviour in the code above.

I have a `$scope.isCollapsed` boolean, that I use in a `ng-repeat-start`-`ng-repeat-stop` block.

From what I understand, I would expect both rows to collapse at the same time as isCollapsed is the same in both case. But what actually happend is that they seems to be independent.

What cause this behaviour ?

The code :

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="person in persons">
    <td>
        <a href="#" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">{{person.name}}</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        {{person.age}}
    </td>
</tr>
<tr collapse="isCollapsed" ng-repeat-end="">
    <td colspan="3">
        <h3>Details about {{person.name}}</h3>
        <p>Some details about {{person.name}}, {{person.age}}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

With the following controller :

```
var app = angular.module('personApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.isCollapsed = true;
    $scope.persons = [{ name: "John",
                        age: "40yrs" },
                      { name: "Kevin",
                        age: "50yrs" }];
});
```

Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojpaNR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-click="collapse()"
```

in controller

```
$scope.collapse=function(){
   $scope.isCollapsed=!$scope.isCollapsed;
}
```

gives expected behaviour

```
why ?
```

Because when you try to change isCollapsed in html it's in a different scope, but when you do it by above function approach it's in the same scope.

To test this you can try

```
ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed;test($index);"
```

and define test as

```
 $scope.test=function(index){
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log('test: '+index);
                console.log('$scope.isCollapsed: '+$scope.isCollapsed);
            },10)
        }
```

It will always print true.

And if you want to use your approach then put it as

```
$rootScope.isCollapsed = true;

ng-click="$root.isCollapsed = !$root.isCollapsed;"
```

*Controllers and some directives that add elements to the dom create their own scope (ng-if, ng-switch, ng-repeat, ng-view etc.). You can use the AngularJS Batarang chrome extension to help debug them. The values are inherited, but setting the value in a child scope breaks the inheritance.*

took above text from 
[Scope variable is not updated on ng-click in views with Angular UI Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371966/scope-variable-is-not-updated-on-ng-click-in-views-with-angular-ui-router)

Comment: I upvoted you for the try but my question is "What cause this behaviour ?" not how to solve it :3

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute specifying the first `tr` element when to collapse. Where as in second `<tr>` element, attribute `collapse="isCollapsed"` will  collapse the element based on `isCollapsed` value.

Comment: I'm talking about the 2 <tr collapse="isCollapsed" ng-repeat-end=""> that will be generated by the ng-repeat (as there is 2 elements in $scope.persons)